# Redirect variable in url to a specific page in apache

Tags: php, regex, apache

I am trying to redirect users to profile page (profile.php)

Here is the link

> https://dev-website.com/name_of_user

And the file is located in

```
~/profile.php
```

If I run this link it works

```
https://dev-website.com/profile.php?username=name_of_user
```

Here is my script

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

Options -Indexes

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d 
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !index.html$
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])(.*)$ https://dev-website.com/profile.php?username=$1 [L]
```

I get this error

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /*name_of_user* was not found on this server.
>
> Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at dev-website.com Port 443

Any help please

Comment: `^(.+[^/])(.*)$` I can't to read it... What should it mean?

Comment: I suggest to start it from `^(.*)$` and debug.

Comment: There are many other redirect inbeteen. This is just part of the htaccess. Anyway I have find the solution look at my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Options -Indexes -MultiViews +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d 
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !index.html$

RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])(.*)$ profile.php?username=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your **.htaccess :**

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

Options -Indexes

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d 
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !index.html$
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])(.*)$ https://dev-website.com/profile.php [L] # <- change
```

And in your **profile.php**, GET the `username`, and preform user specific task like :

```
<?php 

  if( isset($_GET['username'] ) {
     $username = $_GET['username'];
     // do whatever you want as user specific staff here
  }
```

So, the link: `https://dev-website.com/profile.php?username=name_of_user` working prefectly.,

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do this after authentication you should do something like this:

```
if(isValidateUser($username, $pass)){
   header('HTTP/1.0 301');
   header('Location: https://dev-website.com/profile.php?username='.$username));
   die();
}
```

but if you insist to use .htaccess try to use this rule after your appropriate conditions:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])(.*)$ /profile.php?username=$1 [R=301,L]
```